# Как перенести на следующую строчку блочный элемент

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, sass

Привет!Мне нужно перенести надпись "Personal touch" на вторую строчку после иконки.Br не помогает так как это блочный элемент.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/">

    <title>CompanyName</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <!-- Template Basic Images Start -->
    <meta property="og:image" content="path/to/image.jpg">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="img/favicon/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
    <!-- Template Basic Images End -->

    <!-- Custom Browsers Color Start -->
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#FFF">
    <!-- Custom Browsers Color End -->
    <script defer src="libs/fontawesome-free-5.0.8/svg-with-js/js/fontawesome-all.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.min.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row first-block align-items-center">
            <p class="Companyname col-7"><span>company</span><span>name</span></p>
            <ul class="col-5 Top-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="row first-block-2">
            <p class="BigGrayText">
                We’re here to create your
online presense and style
            </p> 
            <p class="SmallGrayText">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  Suspendisse 
mattis orci dapibus risus dignissim, viverra  pellentesque arcu
ullamcorper. Mauris a tincidunt lectus. Proin nec venenatis quam.
<br> <button>start  today  with  us</button> 
            </p>

        </div>
        <div class="row second-block">
            <p class="second-block-bigtext">Features you’ll love</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row  second-block-2">
            <div class="col second-block-2-main">
                <p class="second-block-2-icon"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></p>
                <p class="second-block-2-bigtext">Personal touch</p>
                <p class="second-block-2-smalltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam volutpat purus in ferment uectetur tortor id, pharetra lorem.
                    </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="js/scripts.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Main.sass

```
@import "vars"
@import "fonts"
@import "libs"

ul
    list-style: none

.Companyname
    font-family: $PoiretOne
    color: $white
    font-size: 30px
    margin-top: 74px
    padding-left: 174px
    margin-bottom: 0px
    span:last-child
        color: #C9C9C6
        font-size: 28px 

.first-block
    background-color: $bg-gray
.Top-menu
    display: flex
    margin-top: 75px
    margin-bottom: 0px
    li
        margin-left: 15px
        a
            color: $white
            font-size: 13px
            font-family: $MontserratRegular
            text-decoration: none
            text-transform: uppercase
            &::after
                content: ''
                width: 100%
                height: 2px
                display: block
                background-color: $white
                transform: scale(0)
                transition: all 0.2s 
            &:hover
                    &::after
                        transform: scale(1)
.BigGrayText
    color: $white
    font-size: 50px
    margin-left: 172px
    margin-top: 196px
    font-family: $CabinRegular
    width: 640px
.first-block-2
    background-color: $bg-gray
    button
        background-color: $green
        width: 224px
        height: 56px
        outline: none
        border: none
        color: $white
        text-transform: uppercase
        font-family: $LatoBold
        font-size: 13px
        border-radius: 5px 
        margin-top: 60px
.SmallGrayText
    font-size: 15px
    width: 574px
    margin-left: 174px
    font-family: $LatoLight 
    color: $white
    line-height: 32px
    margin-bottom: 272px
.second-block
    background-color: $white
    &-bigtext
        font-family: $CabinRegular
        font-size: 48px
        width: 100%
        color: $very-dark
        text-align: center
        margin-top: 128px
.second-block-2
    // margin-left: 176px
    // margin-right: 176px
    &-icon
        font-size: 30px
        color: $white
        width: 65px
        height: 65px
        text-align: center
        background-color: $green
        border-radius: 50%
        line-height: 62px
    &-main
        display: flex
        justify-content: center
        flex-wrap: wrap
        width: 329px








@import "media"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поиграйте с `.d-block` возможно

Comment: я могу,конечно ошибаться, но у вас что картинка,что надпись - строчные элементы...вы им задайте display: block...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте к `.second-block-2-main` свойство `flex-direction: column`. И елементы будут в колонку.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так:

```
.second-block-2-icon{clear:both;}
```